# In quest of a rule

Tags: css, 960.gs

Percentage grid width CSS rules such as 960gs and Skeleton grid are really neat and I use them from time-to-time.  However, I was wondering... has someone created a variant where the relative grid cell widths change depending on available window width/screen width.  What I mean is this

Take a 960gs 16 column grid divided into three parts in the proportion 2:12:2, i.e. percentage widths of 12.5:75:12.5.  This works well for large screen sizes.  For smaller screens it is generally better to drop the  column layout and simply stack things one below the other - and that is what I generally do.  But what if you wanted to retain the grid layout?  A system that changes the proportions below a preset "floor" width would be nice.

I am partly thinking out aloud here and plan to see if I can come up with something.  However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel so any pointers to "it has been done already" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note to anyone running into this thread.  The brief answer - without some scripting support it probably is not possible.  If you can live with some scripting the solution is relatively simple.  The steps in brief

1. Wrap your percentage grid cells in a container div
2. Give the container div a dummy class, say "flx" and a data attribute, say data-flx in which you put in a spot of JSON along the lines of

   {"a":"8","b":"16","w":100000},{"a":"18","b":"6","w":"500"},{"a":"12","b":"12","w":"400"}]

Essentially, we define the grid cell proportions to use when the device/screen width falls through a "floor" width.  w:100000 is the default that will work with large screens.  Here I have defined two additional floor levels - 400 pixels and 500 pixels.  My example here assumes two grid cells.  If you have more than 2 cells just put in

```
"c":"proportion", "d":"proportion"
```

etc.  The other bit you need is a spot of jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{$(window).bind("orientationchange resize pageshow",scaleGrids());}

function scaleGrids()
{

 function adaptIt(w,grd)
 {
  var fvd = $(grd).data('flx');
  var ndx = 0;
  for(var i=1;i < 3;i++) if (w < fvd[i].w) ndx = i;
  //the "floor" to use has now been established as fvd[ndx]

  fvd = fvd[ndx];
  var ckls = new Array();
  var cells = $(grd).children();
  ckls.push('st_' + fvd.a);
  ckls.push('st_' + fvd.b);
  //for convenience  we push the proportions to use into an array

  ndx = 0;
  $.each(cells,function(i,cell){$(cell).removeClass().addClass(ckls[ndx++])});
  //iteratively reclass each cell in the grid 
 }

 var w = $(window).width();
 $.each($('.flx'),function(ndx,grd){adaptIt(w,grd)});
 //iteratively rescale each element bearing the class flx
}
```

A brief explanation - when the screen is resized, or the device is rotated, we establish the "floor" on which we find ourselves.  For all DOM elements bearing the class "flx" we iterate through their children (grid cells), strip out all current class declarations and add the new ones.

One final note - for this to really work you need to use a pretty fine grid cell unit size.  I am using a 24 column grid to work with jQuery Mobile.  It is easy to work out the requisite CSS but for the same of completeness I am giving it here anyway

```
.st_1,.st_2,.st_3,.st_4,.st_5,.st_6,.st_7,.st_8,
.st_9,.st_10,.st_11,.st_12,.st_13,.st_14,.st_15,.st_16,
.st_17,.st_18,.st_19,.st_20,.st_21,.st_22,.st_23,.st_24
{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;float:left;}


.flex24{min-height:1em;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0}

.flex24 .st_1{width:4.16666666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_2{width:8.333333333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_3{width:12.5%;}
.flex24 .st_4{width:16.666666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_5{width:20.833333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_6{width:25%;}
.flex24 .st_7{width:29.166666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_8{width:33.33333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_9{width:37.5%;}
.flex24 .st_10{width:41.66666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_11{width:45.83333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_12{width:50%;}
.flex24 .st_13{width:54.16666666667%}
.flex24 .st_14{width:58.33333333333%}
.flex24 .st_15{width:62.5%;}
.flex24 .st_16{width:66.66666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_17{width:70.83333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_18{width:75%;}
.flex24 .st_19{width:79.16666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_20{width:83.33333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_21{width:87.5%;}
.flex24 .st_22{width:91.66666666667%;}
.flex24 .st_23{width:95.83333333333%;}
.flex24 .st_24{width:100%;}
```

A link to a working example will follow.